# Chart using asterisk (loops, arrays)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, charts

So I have an array which creates random numbers and I want to divide the numbers by 10. So if the number is 45 I want to get 6 'p' under each other and 4 asterisks under each other( lets call this whole thing a column). And then I want this with the next number as well but I want these columns to be next to each other not under. It will be easier to understand if you see the picture.
This is what i get:https://gyazo.com/6e4fcf301784e0c385b9ce0d9c938b6a
This is what i want (here there are spaces instead of 'p's: https://gyazo.com/778027ad74a2a3d2065348def8f431cd

This is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = RandomFill(10);
        Print(a);

        int asd = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length-1; i++)
        {
            asd = a[i] / 10;

            for (int j = 0; j <= 10 - asd; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("p");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < asd; k++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("*" + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    static int[] RandomFill(int Length)
    {
        Random rd = new Random();

        int[] array = new int[Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = rd.Next(0, 100);
        }
        return array;
    }

    static void Print(int[] a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach( int element in a)
        {
            Console.Write(element + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, you declared `asd` inside a `for` loop, which means it isn't accessible in the other `for` loops. Unless you have some other instance of `asd` somewhere?

Comment: I used "p" cuz its easier to see for me but Ill change that at the end. And i declared asd inside the for loop cuz i needed the "i" value.

Comment: i know i can declare the asd outside of the loop but that does not change anything with my problem

Comment: Yes it does...your other `for` loops reference `asd` and it is not accessible to them. Please post code that others can copy/paste to reproduce the issue.

Comment: i have changed it

Comment: so you want to go from the top down not from the bottom up, right?

Comment: not sure what u mean but this is what i want : https://gyazo.com/05985f43ff59f62f27ad76396fbf8c70

Answer (score 0):

seems to work...

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                string line = "";
                for (int i = 0; i <= a.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (a[i] >= 10 * (10 - j))
                    {
                        line = line+"*";
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        line = line+"p"; 
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
```

Comment: its actually not what i want cuz these are sideways which i dont want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Console.SetCursorPosition` method to set the cursor position before writing a character. This way you can write one column, then move to the next column without overwriting the previous one.

Note that we want to use `Console.Write` to write the character, because `Console.WriteLine` will append a newline to the end and will mess up our grid.

Assuming you're only using a graph that's 10 characters high (so numbers from 1 to 100), you can determine which rows should be populated inside a loop by subtracting the current iteration from 10 and checking if the number is greater than or equal to that number.

It might make more sense in code:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

static void Main()
{
    // Populate a list of 30 random numbers from 1 to 100
    var randomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0,30).Select(i => rnd.Next(1, 101)).ToList();

    // Output our numbers to the console as column headers
    randomNumbers.ForEach(n => Console.Write(n.ToString().PadLeft(3)));

    // Set the next cursor line as the top of the grid
    var topOfGrid = Console.CursorTop + 1;

    // For each number, divide by 10 and output the result to the console
    for (int rndIndex = 0; rndIndex < randomNumbers.Count; rndIndex++)
    {
        // Capture the left for this column. We multiply the 
        // current index by 3 because we're spacing the columns 
        // 3 characters wide. Then add one so it prints 
        // in the middle of the column
        var columnLeft = 3 * rndIndex + 1;

        var result = randomNumbers[rndIndex] / 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(columnLeft, topOfGrid + i);

            // Determine which character to write by comparing
            // our number with the value of 10 - i
            Console.Write(result >= 10 - i ? "*" : " ");
        }
    }           

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Output**

[image]